# Pusher authorizing error with SPA/React & Laravel Passport

Tags: reactjs, laravel-8, laravel-passport, pusher, laravel-echo

I am trying to listen to a private channel via both web and API guard. The configuration below works fine on web guard. However, I seem to be having trouble with authorizing in API from SPA/React. I am using Laravel Passport as my guard API driver.

**config**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
let e = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  key: KEY,
  cluster: CLUSTER,
  authEndpoint: `/broadcasting/auth`,
  forceTLS: true,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
    }
  }
});
```

**How I try to subscribe in useEffect**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    e.private("orders_36")
      .listen(".OrderChange", (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      })
      .subscribed((e) => console.log(e, "subscribed"))
      .error((e) => console.log(e, "error"));

  }, []);
```

**The error I get**

```
{type: "AuthError", error: "Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status: 405 from /broadcasting/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users", status: 405}
```

I uncommented BroadcastServiceProvider from config/app.php, then I have written the code below in BroadcastServiceProvider.

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
Broadcast::routes([
            'middleware' => 'auth:web,api',
        ]);
```

**routes/channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('orders_{id}', function ($id) {
    return Auth::guard('api')->id() == $id;
});
```

**app/Events/OrderChange.php**

```
class OrderChange implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    public function __construct($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('orders_'.$this->order->user_id);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'OrderChange';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'order' => $this->order,
        ];
    }
}
```

**The code for broadcast calling in Controller**

```
broadcast(new OrderChange(OrderResource::make($order)))->toOthers();
```

I have searched everywhere but the solutions provided do not seem to work.

Comment: This is my problem too. I tried to change "authEndpoint" to "${DOMAIN}/broadcasting/auth
" but it didn't work again and I got 0 status. I checked my route list on the server side and I found "/broadcasting/auth" but I really don't know why it don't work.